# Disabling Magnifying Glass in UITextView in an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, uitextview, touchesmoved

I want to display text and I want to be able to know where in this text a user touches. Because the text could be long, I wanted to use a UITextView so that wrapping and everything would be taken care of. I want my own event handling for when a touch begins or moves. My problem is that the magnifying glass and select/select all menu are interrupting my touchesMoved events.

How can i disable the magnifying glass, but still have user interaction enabled so that I can detect the touches?

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a subclass and override these two functions to disable `select/select all/copy/` and `magnifying`

**`select/select all/copy/`**:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1429320/1526023

**`magnifying`**:

```
- UILongPressGestureRecognizer
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10641203/1526023

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to check the **gestureRecognizers** property.

You will find a lot of them in the array and might want to either remove them all or to find the ones that triggers the event you want to intercept and remove/replace it.

I used it to remove copy/paste and magnifying glass functionalities from an UITextField

Comment: Dwery, how did you do it? I removed 8 gesture recognizers but the magnifying glass is still there when I hold.

Comment: Natan, IIRC gesture recognizers are re-initialized after each event. So i remove the stock recognizers and add my own after each event

Answer (score 0):

You might try the tips offered here:
[How disable Copy, Cut, Select, Select All in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview)