# Disable Magnifying Glass in UITextview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitextview

In `UITextview` when touch is pressed for the longer time magnifying glass shows up. How can i disable it.

Comment: Check out this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866200/disable-magnifying-glass-in-uitextfield)

Comment: Answer is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48077605/4061501). **No subclass needed.**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Finally this issue is also resolved

Here is the code for reference in case anyone needs

in the m file of subclassed UITextview added code

```
-(void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
    //Prevent zooming but not panning
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]) 
    {
        gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
    [super addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    return;
}
```

It works.

Comment: But if I am not mistaken this disables long press totally. In other words, if your text view contains a URL link or a phone number (in case you enabled detections) then on long press your text view won't be able to respond to them, am I right?

Comment: Looking to also disable the caret and text editing? See this answer->[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139234/prevent-editing-of-text-in-uitextfield-and-hide-cursor-caret-magnifying-glass-wh/18139235#18139235)

Comment: Yes, like @antf said, this code totally disable touches on links, phones and events.

Comment: having same issue in ios9, i need to diasble only maginging glass, but not url and phone touch events.

Comment: @Madhu check the answer I just posted. It might give you some insights.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
@implementation CustomTextView 

- (NSArray *)selectionRectsForRange:(UITextRange *)range
{
    self.selectedTextRange = nil;
    return nil;
}

- (void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;

    [super addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    return;
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return NO;
}

- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position
{
    return [super caretRectForPosition:self.endOfDocument];
}


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]] && !gestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
        return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 version of @user1120133's answer:

```
    override func addGestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
      //Prevent long press to show the magnifying glass
      if gestureRecognizer is UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
        gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
      }

      super.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.iOS:

1. Create custom UITextView
2. Override `GestureRecognizerShouldBegin` method on your `UITextView`

```
public override bool GestureRecognizerShouldBegin(UIGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer)
{
    if (gestureRecognizer is UILongPressGestureRecognizer ||
        gestureRecognizer.Name != "UITextInteractionNameLinkTap")
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Irina's answer works partially (Try a tap followed by a long press and you will have a magnifying overlay) for iOS 9.x and crashes on iOS 10 with the following:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You cannot change the delegate
>   of the UIViewControllerPreviewing failure relationship gesture
>   recognizer'

The following code works both for iOS 9.x and 10.x in every combination of tap and/or long gestures I could think of.

> Note **I don't guarantee that it will be accepted by Apple's review**.

```
@implementation CustomTextView

- (void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSArray *allowedGestures = @[ @"UILongPressGestureRecognizer", @"UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer", @"UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer" ];

    if (![allowedGestures containsObject:NSStringFromClass([gestureRecognizer class])])
    {
        return;
    }

    if (([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]] && !gestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded))
    {
        return;
    }

    [super addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}

@end
```

We need `UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer` and `UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer` in order to keep the `UITextView` ability to scroll. Both classes are part of private API **so use that at your own risk.**