# Prevent editing of text in UITextField and hide cursor/caret/magnifying glass while using an inputView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, inputview

How do I prevent the editing of text in a `UITextField` along with hiding the cursor/caret/magnifying glass, but still present the keyboard, as I am using an `inputView` with a `UIPickerView`/`UIDatePickerView`?

Setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` does not work, because it no longer receives any touches and will not present the keyboard.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Subclass UITextField**

```
//Disables caret
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position
{
    return CGRectZero;
}

//Disables magnifying glass
-(void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
    [super addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}
```

**In your UITextFieldDelegate**

```
//Prevent text from being copied and pasted or edited with bluetooth keyboard.
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    return NO;
}
```

Now just set your text programmatically from the result of your UIPickerView/UIDatePicker.

Comment: There are no gesture recognizers (iOS 8):  (lldb) po [textField gestureRecognizers] -> nil

Answer (score 15):

Hiding the cursor is a lot simpler in iOS 7. Still need some trickery to disable the loupe

```
textField.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Still don't know why setting tintColor from storyboard not takes effect, although the code does.

Answer (score 5):

I hope this will helpful for you.

Set cursor UIColor -> Empty. In UI, it will be hidden.

```
[[self.textField valueForKey:@"textInputTraits"] setValue:[UIColor clearColor] forKey:@"insertionPointColor"];
```

Comment: is this a official way to this? I think this is a manipulation of apple's private API.

Comment: This looks suspicious to me! Use Walapu's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found the best solution was

```
- (CGRect) caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition*) position
{
    return CGRectZero;
}

- (NSArray *)selectionRectsForRange:(UITextRange *)range
{
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(copy:) || action == @selector(selectAll:) || action == @selector(paste:))
    {
        returnNO;
    }

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/disabling-the-caret-and-text-entry-in-uitextfields/

Comment: This works, but you can still click and type into the textField unless you also implement **textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:** as per Walapu's answer.

Answer (score 1):

To have a `UITextField` without interaction, but still work with an `inputView`:

**Subclass UITextField with these methods:**

```
// Hide the cursor
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition*)position
{
    return CGRectZero;
}

// All touches inside will be ignored
// and intercepted by the superview
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return NO;
}
```

The last method will single-handedly prevent any editing and the magnifier glass, as you won't be able to tap the `UITextField`.

This works great if you're using a textfield in a `UITableViewCell` for example, and then can toggle firstResponder status through `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

To disable any interaction with textfield except for making it a first responder you can just place a UIButton of the same size right over the textfield. Code for button tap event could be something like this:

```
- (IBAction)btnEditPhoneTapped:(id)sender
{
    if (self.tfClientPhoneNo.isFirstResponder == NO) [self.tfClientPhoneNo becomeFirstResponder];
}
```