# UITextView with large font size and magnifying glass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextView wrapped inside a UIView which can be resized (increasing frame and font size), and the magnifying glass works fine with smaller textview sizes

[image: Magnifying glass working normal]

But if I increase the textview size a lot, the magnifying glass starts going out of its frame

[image]

Can I just remove the magnifying glass without affecting cursor selection, or decrease the scale value inside the glass so the content fits its frame?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640781/disable-magnifying-glass-in-uitextview

Comment: I do not want to remove UILongPressGestureRecognizer, I want to be able to move the cursor inside the textView, just without the magnifying glass, or decrease magnifying glass scale size so the text fits inside magnifying glass' frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, managed to disable magnifying glass without removing the ability to move curser.

To do that, I removed the UILongPressGestureRecognizer to get rid of magnifying glass. Then used my UIPanGestureRecognizer to track the touch location of the user

```
CGPoint currentPos = [panRecognizer locationInView:self];
```

and then set the cursor location

```
UITextPosition *cursorPosition=[self closestPositionToPoint:CGPointMake(currentPos.x, currentPos.y)];
[self setSelectedTextRange:[self textRangeFromPosition:cursorPosition toPosition:cursorPosition]];
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the magnifying glass just set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO`. After that you have to manually call `becomeFirstResponder` when the UITextField is tapped. You can use a `TapGestureRecognizer` to do that.

Comment: I do not wish to disable user interaction altogether, I just want to disable the magnifying glass. Also I have a hitTest that overrides userInteractionEnabled property