# How can I make a UITextView not selectable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How disable Copy, Cut, Select, Select All in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview)

I have some text in a UITextView. I don't want it to be selectable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any features of the UITextView that you need that would not be available with a UILabel in a UIScrollView?  Seems like the only thing you would lose is automatically setting the contentSize, which is easy enough to do manually.

Answer (score 11):

Use 
`myTextView.editable = NO;`

Comment: or (since iOS7) textview.selectable = NO