# Disabling "Define" in a UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a `UITextField` that displays only numeric values (0-9, ., -). When a user selects the contents of the text field, a menu with "copy","paste" and "define" appears. Since the textfield only displays numerical values, I don't want the "define" option to appear. How do I disable the dictionary "define" option in a `UITextField`?

Edit:
I've solved this and posted the solution below

Comment: Something [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits)?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution there. Any specifics?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was "closed as not a real question". Anyway I found the solution. Subclassed UITextField and overided "-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender". By returning 'NO' to if (action == @selector(defineSelection:)), the "define" option was removed from the UIMenuController

Comment: There are those who will close a question if they don't know the right answer.

Comment: This question seems pretty real to me. Thanks for figuring it out.

Comment: Seems that with iOS7, the selector is `_define:`. Instead of relying on a specific undocumented selector name, I used a string comparison: `if ([[NSStringFromSelector(action) lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"define"].location != NSNotFound) { return NO; } else { return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender]; }`

Answer (score 5):

**Swift - iOS 8**

You can do it by subclassing UITextField and overriding `canPerformAction:WithSender` method.

```
class MyTextFieldWithoutDefine: UITextField {
    override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if action == "_define:" {
            return false
        }

        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

List of all actions:

```
cut:
copy:
select:
selectAll:
paste:
delete:
_promptForReplace:
_transliterateChinese:
_showTextStyleOptions:
_define:
_addShortcut:
_accessibilitySpeak:
_accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection:
_accessibilityPauseSpeaking:
makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:
makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:
```

Comment: Big thanks for listing all the available actions. Tested in iOS 9.3 using Obj-C

Answer (score 2):

the solution in the question comment area did not work for me (ios8), i got error with:

`action == @selector(defineSelection:)`

i was able to remove 'define' from edit menu by specifing the options i wanted to include in the menu:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(copy:) ||
        action == @selector(selectAll:)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

more complete answer at: [How to disable copy paste option from UITextField programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701019/how-to-disable-copy-paste-option-from-uitextfield-programmatically)
(thank you serge-k)

Answer (score -1):

If you use a NIB, set the "Correction" property of the UITextField to "NO"(Default value is YES).

If you use code, set the "autocorrectionType" as  "UITextAutocorrectionTypeNO".

Comment: Again, this does not prevent "Define" from showing up in the menu when selecting the contents of the textField.

Comment: I think your question is unclear and we have the wrong idea of what you want to do... You don't want the "Define" option to show up after a long press on the word of interest? The define that performs a lookup in a dictionary?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
UITextField* textField = //...;
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Comment: I set the "correction" property to 'NO' and also tried the above suggestion in code, but still got the 'define' menu option.

Comment: It's in the xib. I also tried your suggestion and set the autocorrectionType to UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo directly in code.

i used:
UITextField *unitValue = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
    unitValue.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;