# Detect if user copies UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, copy, uitextview

I have a UITextView in my app, is there any way I can detect if a user has selected it and copied the text inside?

OR

Is there anyway I can prevent the copy button from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable *copy, paste* functions you should subclass UITextView and add this code to your new class:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
   return NO;
}
```

How to detect pasteboard events such as copying, pasting look here..

[How disable Copy, Cut, Select, Select All in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview)

or here..

[How to disable copy paste option from UITextField programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701019/how-to-disable-copy-paste-option-from-uitextfield-programmatically)

Comment: Won't this also prevent the user from typing at all? Isn't "first responder" causing the keyboard to appear?

Comment: I'll check it when I get home! Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw first comment: indeed, you can't type into something that is not the first responder.