# UITextField how to disable the paste?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

UITextField how to disable the paste?

Comment: This answer was given by PengOne [PengOne](http://stackoverflow.com/users/544050/pengone "PengOne") in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701019/how-to-disable-copy-paste-option-from-uitextfield-programmatically?rq=1

Comment: oh,I'm sorry,I will not repeat the problem later. promise.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

overrides the `canPerformAction:withSender:` method to return `NO` for actions that you don't want to allow:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
    {
        if (action == @selector(paste:))
            return NO;
        if (action == @selector(select:))   
            return NO;   
        if (action == @selector(selectAll:))   
            return NO;  
        return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
    }
```

In Above Code you need to write only for **paste**

**Another way**

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    if (menuController) {
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Also check [This link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**EDITED**

In iOS 7, you can do such like,,

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];
    }];
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

**For Swift User**

```
override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(paste(_:)) {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

---

**If you want to Open Date Picker or Picker view on TEXTFIELD click then below code work.**

Add below two methods in your class.

```
//Hide Menu View
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    if YOURTEXTFIELD.isFirstResponder {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            (sender as? UIMenuController)?.setMenuVisible(false, animated: false)
        })
        return false
    }

    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

**//MUST Implement**

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            return false
}
```

Comment: Isn't working in iOS 7

Comment: This isn't working in iOS7 for me either.

Comment: Last EDITED (i.e  NSOperationQueue) work in iOS 7

Comment: not working in iOS 9.1

Comment: @Balu - In my app used same above code it's working fine in iOS 9.3 too.

Comment: @iPatel -  i tried in simulator. In Device its working. Thankq.