# iOS disable cut/copy in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, copy-paste

Can I disable cut/copy in an iPhone application that displays some text via a label or what not?  This data is purchased and I don't want them passing it around.

Comment: If your security system relies on plaintext not being copied, then you should probably be worrying about more serious considerations...

Comment: This isnt sensitive data, just data that if passed around someway, the other users wouldnt have to purchase the application, just have a single guy send them information by copying and pasting.

Comment: That's exactly why it **is** sensitive data.

Comment: You can follow this link :
[Disable paste in Textbox]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745824/uitextfield-how-to-disable-the-paste
or [Disable paste in uiwebview]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview

Comment: When I say sensitive, its not social security numbers or credit card numbers, its non-personal data.

Comment: Looks like I can disable screenshot, http://tumblr.jeremyjohnstone.com/post/38503925370/how-to-detect-screenshots-on-ios-like-snapchat

Answer (score 2):

Really you should solve this some other way. What's stopping a user from simply writing down the text? But, for the sake of answering the question:

For a `UITextView` override the `canBecomeFirstResponder` function:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
```

And for a `UITextField` override `canPerformAction:withSender:`

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
        return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```