# UITextField with Copy option and method that tell Copy action is done

Tags: ios, objective-c, copy, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` that contains code to activate an app. For that `UITextField`, I want the Copy option only. I can do this by [overriding `canPerformAction:withSender:`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6701104/1066828)

However I want to know, is there any `IBAction` or delegate which will tell me that copying is done?

What I want to do is after clicking Copy, I directly want to go to screen where I will paste the code and get the app activated.

Any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make custom MenuController as following:

```
UIMenuItem *copy = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"copy" action:@selector(copy)];
UIMenuItem *paste = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"paste" action:@selector(paste)];
UIMenuItem *deleteAll = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"deleteAll" action:@selector(deleteAll)];

UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
[menu setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:copy, paste, deleteAll, nil]];

[menu setTargetRect:self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame inView:self.view];

[menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

In  `ViewDidLoad` before initialising menu controller write this line   `[self canBecomeFirstResponder];`

Hope this helps