# How to limit the numbers in the text field in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift

I want the user to fill in the textfield a number from 0 to 60.
How can i limit the number chars to 2?
How to limit the maximum number to 60?
And how to cancel the 'paste' option on the textfield so the user won't be able to paste letters?

Comment: this is for disable copy/paste: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701019/how-to-disable-copy-paste-option-from-uitextfield-programmatically

Comment: @HoaParis This is in Objective-C, can you provide it in swift?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think there are 2 ways you can do that.

Implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement function

```
func textField(textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    var startString = ""

    if textField.text != nil {
        startString += textField.text!
    }

    startString += string

    var limitNumber = startString.toInt()

    if limitNumber > 60 {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

In this Each time check what has been entered to the `UITextField` so far, convert to Integer and if the new value is higher than 60, return false. (Also show the appropriate error to the user).

I think a much better way would be to provide `UIPickerView`.

Comment: I prefer for my code the textfield, but can you continue the code? I didn't get what I need to do after your code.

Comment: This is the answer! great! do you know what i need to do if I got 2 text fields?

Comment: Suppose you have 2 textFields, ageTextField and heightTextField.
The first argument received in the function is of textField
On top you put the check 
if (textField == ageTextField) and execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use  textfield's delegate method

Where 10 is Max limit for text field...

```
      func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let newLength = countElements(textField.text) + countElements(string) - range.length
       return newLength <= 10 // Bool
 }
```

If countElements not work in latest version of s
wift use count instead of countElements.

Answer (score 0):

To disable copy and paste:

```
func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool
{
    if action == "paste:"
        {return false}
    return super.canPerformAction(action,withSender:sender)
}
```