# Disable copy, paste in UITextfield is not working in iOS 9.x

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, uimenucontroller

I created a text field in one class BBCustomUtility.h,.m class files and then

```
+(UITextField*)createTextField: (CGRect)rect image:(NSString*)imageName tag:(int)tag secureText:(BOOL)entry placeh:(NSString*)placeholder
{
    UITextField *transactionField = [ [ UITextField alloc ] initWithFrame: rect ];
    transactionField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    transactionField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    transactionField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    transactionField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    transactionField.placeholder = placeholder;
    transactionField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    transactionField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    transactionField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; 
    transactionField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; 
    transactionField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    transactionField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    transactionField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    transactionField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    transactionField.tag = tag;
    transactionField.delegate = self;
    transactionField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; 
    transactionField.text = @"";
    [ transactionField setEnabled: YES ];
    transactionField.secureTextEntry = entry;
    return transactionField ;
}
```

importing from common class and used in class1.m

```
mPasswordField1 = [BBCustomUtility createTextField:CGRectMake(IS_WIDTH_DEVICE/2-120, 140, 50, 50) image:@"txtField_bg_50.png" tag:1 secureText:YES placeh:[shareObj.mLabelDictionary valueForKey:@""]];
    mPasswordField1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    mPasswordField1.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    mPasswordField1.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:mPasswordField1];
```

tried to disable copy paste option on textfield in the below methods these are not working for me

```
1)
    -(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
    {
        // Returning 'NO' here disables all actions on textfield
        return NO;
    }   // not working still showing the paste option on textfield
```

2)

```
 -(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
    {
        if (action == @selector(copy:) || action == @selector(paste:)) {
            return NO;
        }
       return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
    }  // this is also not working still showing the paste option
```

3)

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {

        if ([mPasswordField1 respondsToSelector:@selector(inputAssistantItem)])
        {
            UITextInputAssistantItem *inputAssistantItem = [mPasswordField1 inputAssistantItem];
            inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
            inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
        }
    } // this also not working
```

can any one please tell me what's the mistake i did in my code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add below method in your code and that`s it,

```
 - (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];
}];
return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

It will disable all types of edit.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I am up voting right now but this is not good to ask up vote question as per stacdkoverflow's guideline.

Comment: Is there an equivalent method / code snippet to this that is not deprecated on iOS 13 & 14?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

-canPerformAction:withSender: should be in a subclass of UITextField. It doesn't look like you subclassed because you are allocating a UITextField.

Comment: yes i'm not using subclass of UITextField. Can you please tell me if with out subclass of uitextfield

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply that only to one special textfield like a password:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if([self.textFieldPassword isFirstResponder]){
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];
        }];
    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Another option is directly to avoid the selection of the Textfield implementing the UITextFieldDelegate and making this in its methods:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
 //This code has side effects in the UISearchbar (white field is no more disappearing):
 - (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
 [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO  animated:NO];
}];
return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(false, animated: false)
    }
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```