# Disabling menu on tap of UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

How do we disable Cut-Copy-Paste or Select-SelectAll menu when tapped on a UITextField. I tried with below code but it did not work.

```
if ([UIMenuController sharedMenuController]) {
    [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How disable Copy, Cut, Select, Select All in UITextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview)

Answer (score 2):

Make a subclass if UITextView and implement this function

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
   if (action == @selector(paste:) || action == @selector(copy:))//and put other actions also
      return NO;
   return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`canBecomeFirstResponderhere` should do the trick. make sure you delegate your `UITextField`

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
```