# NSLog UIGestureRecognizer description?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, nslog

how to get in the consol using NSLog, the list of gestureRecogniser on UITextView?

something like that?

```
NSLog([UIGestureRecognizer description]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, something like this:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *g in textView.gestureRecognizers) {
    NSLog(@"g %@", g);
}
```

Comment: I need to prevent event: twoFingerSingleTap on UITextView. there is possible? If yes you have an idea?

Comment: @benhi: search-engine here works by searching question titles so it would be best (for others searching for the same thing) if you put this in another question. And don't forget to accept beryllium's answer.

Comment: @benhi, Yes, it looks like another question. But i hope it help you - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1426731/194544

Comment: click the checkmark in the upper left corner of the answer field