# Dismiss select/paste menu in UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'd like to programmatically dismiss the select/paste/copy etc menu in a `UITextView`. I know how to [prevent it from appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview), but I'd also like to be able to dismiss an open one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to dismiss it, just remove the `UITextView`'s responder. For example, you want to dismiss it when the user touches outside the popup menu (which, btw, already happens by default!). For this, you can do:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
   [yourTextView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Well, by reading the fscking docs I found another answer: [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO]; The hard part is getting my interaction right. I still want the users to be able to select text in a sensible way, but that's a whole other story.