# I don't want that magnifying glass appears below UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have an UITextView. Magnifying glass will appear if I select some text. Magnifying glass may appear below UITextView.  Is it possible to restrict magnifying glass boundaries?

[image]

Comment: You can also check [How disable Copy, Cut, Select, Select All in UITextView][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subclass the `UITextView` and override `canPreformAction` like this :

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    BOOL can = [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];

    if(action == @selector(paste:) || action == @selector(selectAll:) || action == @selector(select:))
        can = NO;

    return can;
}
```

This is will prevent the UIMenuController To Appear .. but the magnify glass will still shown.