# How to subclass UITextView 

Tags: iphone, uitextview, subclass, uiactionsheet, uiresponder

How can I subclass `UITextView` in `UIActionSheet` to overwrite `canBeforeFirstResponder` to  `disable copy, select, and select all` in `UITextView`.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class English;

@protocol EnglishDelegate

- (void)dismissViewDidFinish:(UIViewController *)viewController;

@end


@interface English: UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>


{
id<EnglishDelegate> delegate;
UITextView *textView;
UINavigationBar *navBar;
UINavigationController *navigationController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *textView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UINavigationBar *navBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<EnglishDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView; 

-(void)dismissView:(id)sender;

@end
```

Anyone knows how to subclass it in h file.

Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How disable Copy, Cut, Select, Select All in UITextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't subclass `UITextView` inside of another class; you would just plain subclass it in another file and override the `canBecomeFirstResponder` as so:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: you mean to say in m file i can subclass it.

Comment: You can subclass it in a `.h` file and override methods in the corresponding `.m` file.

Comment: Without subclassing it can i override the canBecomefirstresponder or there is other way of disabling the copy paste menu

Comment: The best way to disable pasteboard operations in a `UITextView` is to subclass it and override `canBecomeFirstResponder`; the only way to override it is by subclassing `UITextView`.