# Enable scroll property and disable (copy,selectAll,define) properties at a time in UItextview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Hi,

I am developing an app in Xcode 4.3.2. I have a small question that is I want to enable scroll view property of `UITextView` and Disable the (copy,selectAll,define) properties of `UITextView` at a time in my code.

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `UITextView` and overwrite `canBecomeFirstResponder`:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I used text views through Interface Builder. Can I achieve my issue with this solution I tried but not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

## subclassing!

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return NO;
}
```