# How to disable magnification in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, magnification, nsdatadetector

I want to get rid of magnification and text selection in UITextView but I need phone number, link and address detectors. I am using

```
-(void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
    [super addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    return;}
```

to stop magnification, but it also stops selection phone number / address / link detected by textview.
If I do `[_txtView setSelectable:NO];` it stops both magnification and text selection as well as data detection.

Answer (score 2):

After quite a long time trying, I managed to stop text selection, magnifying, and keeping data detection (links clickable etc) by overriding addGestureRecognizer on a UITextView subclass allowing only UILongPressGestureRecognizer delaying touch ending:

UIUnselectableTextView.m

```
-(void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]] && gestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded)
    {
        [super addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put image on your UITextview in .xib file then put below code.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

      UITapGestureRecognizer *tappress= [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(longPressed:)];
      img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
      [img addGestureRecognizer:tappress];
}

-(void)longPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [yourtextview becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

in my code img is a UIImageview

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Set the delegate of the textview to your viewcontroller
2. add this method

   ```
   - (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
   {
        NSRange selected;
        selected.location = 0;
        selected.length = 0;
        textView.selectedRange = selected;
   }
   ```

This would disable the magnification but still have links clickable

Answer (score -3):

You just need to make sure you have set right parameters for the UItextfield (and there is no need to actually have it done by overriding the gestures). I guess if you change your attributes for "Behaviour" and "Detection" in interface builder as following you will have your desired behaviour.[image]

Comment: if Selectable is unchecked detection doesn't work even if all the detection are marked as checked