# UITextField with partial edit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I want to use a `UITextField` so that only part of it will be editable.

I know about the delegation and `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` but for some reason, copying the ranged part is allowed.

My goal is to get similar result to [this](https://csvcontacts.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/broadcast_email.png) (the 'subject' text part) without being able to copy it.

Should i use a different `UITextField` with `textFieldDidBeginEditing` returning false all the time?

Is there a better solution?

Comment: You refer to the screenshot. That seems to be either a placeholder or a label next to the UITextField.

Comment: It's not a place holder, its the regular mail 'Subject' label.
So an extra field is the best practice for this one?

Comment: An extra UILabel, yes. This way you can style it to your liking as well.

Comment: If you want to disable copy & paste actions, you could try to implement one of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the screenshot, a UILabel placed next to the UITextField is used. I'd recommend doing this as it will give you more options when you decide to style the text.