# How to control/Hide shortcut action in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

Here I have a custom UITextView. It shows many of the shortcuts that is not needed and also it shows wrong action, like when textview is empty it shows the "cut" "copy" "select" & "select all" action that is not required. Please refer to the screenshot for more clarity. [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMRPr.png)

[image: screen shot]

[image]

Comment: Don't tell people to vote on your post, people will vote as they see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to disable the entire Select/Copy/Paste Menu in a UITextView

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{    
  [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
  return NO;    
}
```

Comment: For Swift 3

`override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return false
}`

Comment: I don't want to disable the entire menu.I just want normal textview behavior.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview check this ans