# How to remove the iPad's bottom copy/paste bar when editing a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have an app that allows the user to edit a `UITextView`, however the copy/paste/cut bar pops on the iPad, blocking some of the bottom of the interface, as the following screenshot shows:

[image]

I would prefer getting rid of it instead of adjusting the interface, is there any way to accomplish this?

NOTE: This only appears on the iPad!

**EDIT**: My UITextView is entirely editable, therefore, this is not a duplicate of [How disable Copy, Cut, Select, Select All in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview) ! Also, I don't want to just disable the buttons, I want the whole bottom bar to go away!

**EDIT 2**: Updated the image for more clarity, as some answers are addressing the small black one that appears near the cursor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How disable Copy, Cut, Select, Select All in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide this as below,

```
yourTextView.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
yourTextView.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!